# Cypher query for ordered list

Tags: list, neo4j, cypher

I have an ordered list

(parent)-[:NEXT]->(item)-[:NEXT]->(item)...[:NEXT]->(item)

I am trying to figure out efficient cypher query for finding all the items. Relation :NEXT only goes from one item to next one and is never duplicate and I don't have a cycle.

This is my cypher query

```
START n=node(nodeId) MATCH (n)-[r:NEXT*]->(m:ListItem) RETURN distinct(m)
```

This works but is incredibly slow even for lists having 10 items because it apparently goes the query around. For a list having length 3 and * replaced with *1..3 and distinct removed, I got 45 nodes. I don't really understand why. With distinct I get the 3 nodes I think I am supposed to get.

Comment: Please give an example of data.

Comment: Couldn't find a way to easily export data that would help to play around. What would be good way to export example data to be displayed here? But I found a solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to do it efficiently (assuming all list items are linked to parent by relation LIST_ITEM

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n)={nodeId} WITH n
      MATCH (n)-[:LIST_ITEM]-(m:ListItem) WHERE NOT (m)-[:NEXT]->() 
      WITH n, m 
      MATCH path = (n)-[:NEXT*]->(m) 
      RETURN FILTER (a in nodes(path) WHERE ANY (l in labels(a) WHERE l="ListItem")) 
      LIMIT 1
```

Simpler queries are welcome

Comment: Note that with recent versions of Neo4j, the proper way to find a node by id is `MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = {nodeId}`. The use of `START` is limited to legacy indices since Cypher 2.2.

Comment: The 2 relationships you use here have different functions. Is `m` in the question a `ListItem` also? Is it a "parent" or the head of the linked list?

Comment: I edited my reply because apparently I used `m` and `p` for the same node to confuse people. `m` is `ListItem` too. Originally my problem was also - I didn't notice it - that I had `:NEXT` relationship from `n` to itself which lengthened the queries.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your problem, you're looking for one of the *complete* paths when traversing the `:NEXT` relationship, but not necessarily the *longest* path. It's unclear whether traversing `:NEXT` relationships always leads to `ListItem` nodes, based on the query in your own answer.

Your query can be simplified to:

```
MATCH p = (head:ListItem)-[:NEXT*]->(tail:ListItem)
WHERE id(head) = {nodeId}
  AND NOT (tail)-[:NEXT]->()
RETURN filter(n IN nodes(p) WHERE n:ListItem)
LIMIT 1
```

or even, if there are only `ListItem` nodes in the path:

```
MATCH p = (head:ListItem)-[:NEXT*]->(tail:ListItem)
WHERE id(head) = {nodeId}
  AND NOT (tail)-[:NEXT]->()
RETURN nodes(p)
LIMIT 1
```

There's no need to scan the items through the `:LIST_ITEM` relationships to find the possible tails since you're going to traverse the variable-length relationship anyway, to find the nodes in the path: just do the traversal and only include the paths which can't be expanded.